# Problem access to GPIO rasbery pi 3 with android things

Tags: gpio, android-things

I want to turn on A LED with android things and raspberry Pi 3. I did it as instructed in https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/gpio. And I am using last android things version (1.0.15). 
any comments why I get a such error?

> 2009-01-01 03:30:07.762 667-667/com.inflashpay.inflash
>   E/Request Permission: List of available ports: [BCM2] 2009-01-01
>   03:30:07.774 667-667/com.inflashpay.inflash E/Request Permission:
>   Unable to access GPIO
>       com.google.android.things.pio.PioException: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: BCM2 failed to apply the required
>   pin mux: No such file or directory (code 2)

added:

```
private static final String LED = "BCM2";
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Gpio mLedGpio;
    PeripheralManager service = PeripheralManager.getInstance();
    Log.i(TAG, "Available GPIO: " + service.getGpioList());
    try {

        mLedGpio = service.openGpio(LED);
        mLedGpio.setDirection(Gpio.DIRECTION_OUT_INITIALLY_LOW);
        Log.i(TAG, "Start blinking LED GPIO pin");
        // Post a Runnable that continuously switch the state of the GPIO, blinking the
        // corresponding LED
        mHandler.post(mBlinkRunnable);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error on PeripheralIO API", e);
    }
```

Comment: Which GPIO name are you using to open the port?

Comment: I use different ones but BCM2, BCM21 are the most!

Comment: Please add the source code.

Comment: source code added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified CONFIG file because I needed to use a monitor needed to change resolution there, and when I restored it to default problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

The code sounds good, but the problem is probably the GPIO name.

Check out the pinout diagram of the Raspberry Pi

[image: Raspberry Pi Pinout diagram]

You can see that BCM2 is not available (although BCM21 is)

You can see another example that uses the pins on the Rainbow HAT [on this sample](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Android-Things-Quick-Start-Guide/blob/master/chapter3-gpio/src/main/java/com/plattysoft/gpiosamples/BlinkTimerActivity.kt). That one I have run and verified that works. Feel free to compare the project with yours or clone the repo and try that code.

Comment: I used ur codes and get same problem with different GPIOs such as BCM16, 21 ,...

Comment: Yes, I did. and get such error:  Caused by: com.google.android.things.pio.PioException: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: BCM6 failed to apply the required pin mux: No such file or directory (code 2)

Comment: I'm confused with the logs. Is this crashing when trying to ger the GPIO list, when trying to open the GPIO pin, or when trying to change it inside the runnable?

Comment: It reports GPIO list very good and all GPIOs. but when I want to open it it gets error. It's not about runnable!